# How do I append unique IDs to an existing URL based on current date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

I need to be able to add a 4 character ID code to the end of a URL based on the current date.

I have an array with 31 codes (One for each day in July). Each day the URL should have the next string in the array added to the end. I'm not trying to add a random string or anything, I just want to correspond each string to a day of the month but have a single URL that changes dynamically.

Currently, I am able to add a single static ID to the URL but I don't know to proceed

Here what I have so far:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("dealbtn");

function changeImg() {
    btn.href = "";

    const ID = ["mp2y","ymhm","rdkx","rcvq","xf8g","zd9h","323c","uqqa","fvfr","vwdm","kqvu","wrwu","ia7v","m6db","vfmp","ifg8","8re4","hwrp","nzv8","a7da","bzek","anbt","a8vr","tfx3","4n42","anxq","3aa8","yxj6","hwqt","vmbi","b6qe"]

    for(let i=0; i<ID.length; i++){
    };

    
    const day = new Date().getDate();

    btn.href = `https://www.testsite.com/medialibary/uploads/Test-img-${day + ID[0]}.jpg`

};

changeImg();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the ID using the day number as the index. Reduce the index by 1 to compensate for the fact that the calendar days start form 1 and arrays start from 0.

```js
const ID = ["mp2y","ymhm","rdkx","rcvq","xf8g","zd9h","323c","uqqa","fvfr","vwdm","kqvu","wrwu","ia7v","m6db","vfmp","ifg8","8re4","hwrp","nzv8","a7da","bzek","anbt","a8vr","tfx3","4n42","anxq","3aa8","yxj6","hwqt","vmbi","b6qe"]
    
const day = new Date().getDate();

//btn.href = `https://www.testsite.com/medialibary/uploads/Test-img-${ID[day-1]}.jpg`
console.log('using '+ID[day-1])
```

Comment: That was super simple! thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it was of use to you :) you can mark it as the answer to your question so that the question is closed